Error por funcion no definida
tengo el siguiente codigo
<?php
$alumnos = array ( ['id'=>1, 'nombre'=>'Victor', 'apellido'=>'Álvarez', 'correo'=>'victor@mail.com', 'curso'=>'PHP'],
['id'=>2, 'nombre'=>'Maria', 'apellido'=>'Sánchez', 'correo'=>'maria@mail.com', 'curso'=>'PHP'],
['id'=>3, 'nombre'=>'Carlos', 'apellido'=>'Torres', 'correo'=>'carlos@mail.com', 'curso'=>'PHP'],);
$tabla_html = "<table border='1'>";
$tabla_html.="<th>ID</th><th>NOMBRE</th><th>APELLIDO</th><th>CORREO</th><th>CURSO</th>";
$tabla_html.="<tbody>";
while ($fila = current($alumnos)){
    //var_dump($fila);
    $fila="<tr>";
    while(list($clave, $valor) = each($fila)){
        $tabla_html.="<td>".$valor."</td>";
    }
    $tabla_html.="</tr>";
    $fila = next($alumnos);
}
$tabla_html.="</tbody></table>";
echo $tabla_html;
?>

al ejecutar me da error y no consigo averiguar la solución.
llevo toda la tarde dando vueltas al codigo y no consigo subsanar el error
se que esta en el each($fila) del segundo while ya que es donde me reporta el error
cuando ejecuto el codigo en el navegador
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prueba\TurorialPHP\Ejercicio4.php:30 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prueba\TurorialPHP\Ejercicio4.php on line 30 El array es mas largo por eso me da error en la linea 30, pero hace referencia al each()

yo creo que el error esta en la linea que dice el mensaje de error ...

si eso es lo que me reporta el navegador pero cual es el error?

el que dice la linea que reporta el error ...

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prueba\TurorialPHP\Ejercicio4.php:30 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prueba\TurorialPHP\Ejercicio4.php on line 30                  El array es mas largo por eso me da error en la linea 30, pero hace referencia al each()

esa informacion deberia estar en tu publicacion desde el inicio ... no en los comentarios

he publicado poco

te recomiendo hacer el [tour] , hay te explican como usar el sitio.

En la version 7 y 5 esa funcion aun esta definida, no deberias de tener ese error, valida la version que tienes de php en ejecucion y actualiza/edita los tags de tu pregunta/publicacion.

El error habla por si mismo, te indica que la función each no existe, no existe porque la función each está obsoleta desde php 7.2 y fue definitivamente eliminada en php 8 como indica la documentación oficial. Por ello NO debe usarse, y definitivamente lanzará este error si trabajas en la versión 8 de php o posterior.
¿Por qué no pruebas de hacer un foreach?
Mirando el código puedo ver lo que también tienes otro problema, estás sobreescribiendo el valor de $fila cuando dentro del primer while la sobrescribes por un string: $fila="<tr>";, entiendo que realmente quieres poner: $tabla_html.="<tr>";
Usando while
En caso de querer usar si o si un bucle while tendrás que encontrar una alternativa que no contemple usar la función each como por ejemplo:  repetir el mismo while que has hecho para recorrer los alumnos, pero en este caso recorriendo las propiedades del alumno.
while ($datoAlumno = current($fila)) {
   $tabla_html.="<td>".$datoAlumno."</td>";
   $datoAlumno = next($fila);
}


al cambiar lo que me comentas me sigue arrojando el error en la misma linea del each. respecto a lo de utilizar un foreach, me piden que sea a traves de while

@user355973 ahora que has aportado el output del error y la restricción de usar while, he actualizado la respuesta aclarando el porqué del error y una alternativa.

perfecto era hacer el mismo while como me has aportado muchisimas graciass

@user355973 me alegra, si la respuesta te ha servido, márcala como la solución a tu pregunta, así el tema queda "cerrado" saludos.

SEgun los tags esta usando php 7 y 5 ... no entiendo de donde sacas que la funcion each esta obsoleta sin saber la version de php que esta usando ...

¿Según que tags @FranciscoNuñezIALover? No hay tags que definan una versión de php, y la excepción que indica Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each() solo puede salir a partir de php8. Lo saco de la documentación oficial, en la ES indica que está obsoleta desde php 7.2 y en la EN dice que a partir de la versión 8 está eliminada, por ello el error de función indefinida.
Puedes validarlo en este sandbox da warning en v7.x y undefined en v8

viste los tag que uso en su pregunta???
